# Cannot convert object to a string

Tags: c#

I have encrypted every item in MS Access file using AES. Encryption works great. The problem is that I am getting an error: `Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'` On lines like these: `security.Decrypt(readPersonalData.GetValue(1), storedAuth.Password, storedAuth.UserName)`

How can I avoid this?

```
        if (readPersonalData.HasRows)
        {
            while (readPersonalData.Read())
            {
                // Count all entries read from the reader.
                countEntries++;


                txtDisplay.Text += "=== Entry ID: " + readPersonalData.GetValue(0) + " ===" + Environment.NewLine;
                txtDisplay.Text += "Type: " + security.Decrypt(readPersonalData.GetValue(1), storedAuth.Password, storedAuth.UserName) + Environment.NewLine;
                if (!readPersonalData.IsDBNull(2)) txtDisplay.Text += "URL: " + security.Decrypt(readPersonalData.GetValue(2), storedAuth.Password, storedAuth.UserName) + Environment.NewLine;
                if (!readPersonalData.IsDBNull(3)) txtDisplay.Text += "Software Name: " + security.Decrypt(readPersonalData.GetValue(3), storedAuth.Password, storedAuth.UserName) + Environment.NewLine;
                if (!readPersonalData.IsDBNull(4)) txtDisplay.Text += "Serial Code: " + security.Decrypt(readPersonalData.GetValue(4), storedAuth.Password, storedAuth.UserName) + Environment.NewLine;
                if (!readPersonalData.IsDBNull(5)) txtDisplay.Text += "User Name: " + security.Decrypt(readPersonalData.GetValue(5), storedAuth.Password, storedAuth.UserName) + Environment.NewLine;
                if (!readPersonalData.IsDBNull(6)) txtDisplay.Text += "Password: " + security.Decrypt(readPersonalData.GetValue(6), storedAuth.Password, storedAuth.UserName) + Environment.NewLine;
                txtDisplay.Text += Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What if you add a ToString() after your GetValue(1)?

Comment: Does not work. I have tried that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try -

```
txtDisplay.Text += "Type: " + security.Decrypt(readPersonalData.GetString(1), storedAuth.Password, storedAuth.UserName) + Environment.NewLine;
```

Which should return a string that can be passed to the `security.Decrypt` function.

Comment: @NewHelpNeeder, it is better that you upvote the answer besides accepting it, to express that it was useful.